# error NG8001: 'componentName' is not a known element. It was already imported in module file though I am getting this error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular14

My Angular application was made in version 5. I have upgraded it to the version 14. After upgradation when I tried to run the application, I got error NG8001 for many components which are already imported and set in the declaration section in the main `app.module.ts` file.

Here is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@mobiscroll/angular-lite": "^4.7.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^15.2.9",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^5.3.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.91",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular-confirmation-popover": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-star-rating": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angular4-carousel": "^3.1.8",
    "angular4-social-login": "^1.1.0",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^5.0.3",
    "ng2-dragula": "^5.0.1",
    "ng2-meta": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-owl-carousel2": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.9",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-meta": "0.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^4.1.4",
    "ngx-stripe": "^14.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "screenfull": "^4.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.9",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng2-scrollable": "^0.8.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
```

Error:

> **error NG8001: 'backgroundimg' is not a known element**
> backgroundimg component is used in component named "TherapistHeaderComponent" and that component is imported in main app.module file

app.module.ts

```
import { TherapistHeadersComponent } from './therapist/therapist-headers/therapist-headers.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     TherapistHeadersComponent,
  ]
})
```

Same error coming for library's component:

> **error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'matMenu'.**

Again matMenu is used in the same component (TherapistHeader which is described above) that component is imported! And matMenuModule is also imported in main app.module.ts file

app.module.ts

```
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { TherapistHeadersComponent } from './therapist/therapist-headers/therapist-headers.component';


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     TherapistHeadersComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
     MatMenuModule
  ]
})
```

This error is coming for multiple components.